# Sending files and other data using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file

I am trying to send data to server which includes files and strings with ajax. My code in jsp is:

```
<html>
...
<body>
...
    <form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="classroomID" type="hidden" value="1" />
        <input type="file" name="file" size="30" id="file" />
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript"
        src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='sendUpload.js'></script>
...
</body>
</html>
```

And my sendUpload.js looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("here");

    $("form#data").submit(function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        console.log("Submitted");
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        console.log(JSON.stringify(formData));

        $.ajax({
            url: "UploadServlet",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data)
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

But the JSON data is empty. any suggestions? I am using java servlet.

Comment: Can you please share the errors you get with us?

Comment: @Catalyst no I changed it so that it works but it doesn't have any data for some reason. JSON.stringify is empy but there should at least be classroomID with value 1.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of errors are you getting? Looks like your jquery selector is wrong, i'd try changing this:

```
$("form#data").submit(function(ev){
```

To this:

```
$("#data").submit(function(ev){
```

Not really sure though, you should post the specific errors.

Comment: It doesn't change anything. I no longer get errors but now problem is the JSON data is empty even though I uploaded file and there is hidden input with value 1.

Comment: Try adding in these options:       async: true,
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

Comment: At what stage is it breaking? Have you verified that the servlet is not receiving the form submission?

Comment: yes I have. the JSON data (FormData) is empty so even if it receives there wouldn't be any effect.

Comment: Kind of just spit balling at this point, but what about:       data: new FormData( this ),

Comment: Look formData is empty itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('classroomID', $('#classroomID').val());
formData.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);
```

...and give your classroomID input field an id of 'classroomID'.

Also, you cannot inspect formData directly from the console so you will have to use this to debug:

```
for (var item of formData) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: I also want classroomID input to send. What can I do in this case?

Comment: Just append the classroomID field to the formData object. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I did it and it gives the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Try amending this line to: formData.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);

Comment: You won't be able to inspect 'formData' directly from the console so you will have to iterate over each item and log to the console. I have updated my answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form#data").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "UploadServlet",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              classroomID: $('input[name="classroomID"]').val(),
              file: $('input[name="file"]').val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Does it work for you?